# Odoo specify addons paths as a pattern?

Tags: configuration, path, odoo

Is it possible to specify odoo addons paths as a pattern?

I have a directory where I keep modules separated by projects, like this:

```
~/source/:
  project1/
    /module1
    /module2
  project2/
    /module3
    /module4
```

And so on. Now if I want to specify all my modules paths, I need to manually specify every project directory as addons path. And if there gonna be new projects, I will need to update the path.

But if I could specify something like:

`--addons-path=~/source/*/`, so it would load all projects as addons path, it would work way more dynamically. But doing this, just gives me error that there is no such directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odoo doesn't allow this kind of wildcard syntax.

This configuration is a [simple split on comma](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/547204b7f4a81b6915c9f84754080dd3195950e9/openerp/tools/config.py#L478-L480) with only a replacement of home directory (`~` on unix) and environment variables.

You could use a shell or bash script to do this, for example in a linux shell you could use when starting odoo by command line:

```
--addons-path=$(echo ~/source/* | tr ' ' ,)
```

the `tr ' ' ,` command is used to replace the spaces introduce by the wildcards by comma which is the path separator expected by odoo.